# Twilio status says Delivered but the SMS was not received

Tags: twilio-api

We are using Twilio to send SMS messages through our C# application.

We are in the US. When sending SMS to US mobile numbers, the app works as expected.

However, when our app tries to send to a Malaysia mobile, everything seems to work in the app. No errors. Plus the Twilio message logs say "Delivered", but the user does NOT get the SMS.

However, it does look like another Malaysian user is able to receive the SMS message.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an issue with just one particular user, it might be a device-specific issue (have noticed this in the past with iPhones on DND mode when sending messages from US numbers to Indian users) or an issue with a particular local cellular carrier.

Have you been able to evaluate what's different between the two Malaysian users (different device models, different carriers, etc.)?